# Find the right pattern for code duplication

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a car service that is using car api to work with the car. The problem is that I use get_driver_car in every single method of my service to get the car object and in the end I use update_car method to save the data. From my perspective, it seems like these two methods can be used from another method but I have no idea how to refactor this code. I would be glad to hear all suggestions

```
class CarService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.api = CarApiService()

    def add_branding(self, car_id: str):
        car = self.api.get_driver_car(json.dumps({'car_id': car_id}))['car']
        if 'sticker' not in car['amenities']:
            car['amenities'].append('sticker')

        if 'lightbox' not in car['amenities']:
            car['amenities'].append('lightbox')

        return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})

    def remove_branding(self, car_id: str):
        car = self.api.get_driver_car(json.dumps({'car_id': car_id}))['car']
        
        if 'sticker' in car['amenities']:
            del car['amenities'][car['amenities'].index('sticker')]

        if 'lightbox' in car['amenities']:
            del car['amenities'][car['amenities'].index('lightbox')]

        return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})

    def add_booster(self, car_id:str):
        car = self.api.get_driver_car(json.dumps({'car_id': car_id}))['car']

        if car['booster_count'] == 0:
            car['booster_count'] = 1
        else:
            return None

        return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})

    def remove_booster(self, car_id: str):
        car = self.api.get_driver_car(json.dumps({'car_id': car_id}))['car']

        if car['booster_count'] == 1:
            car['booster_count'] = 0
        else:
            return None

        return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})
    def create_car_request(self, car: dict) -> dict:
        del car['is_readonly']
        del car['created_date']

        return car
```

Comment: The pattern is called "extract method", if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Or https://refactoring.guru/parameterize-method

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic step towards optimizing something like this is to create helper methods for the repeated logic.

We can replace a complicated line of code:

```
return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})
```

With a simple one:

```
return self._update_helper(car_id, car)
```

By implementing an internal helper method:

```
def _update_helper(self, car_id: str, car: dict):
    return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})
```

---

All of your repetitive methods share the same structure:

1. Access the car from the API.
2. Perform some modification on the car.
3. Send the modified car back to the API.

The differences exist only in step #2.  You should be able to create some sort of wrapper or [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-decorators) to take a step #2 modification and turn it into a complete function.

Unfortunately I don't code in Python so I'm unsure of the syntax here.

```
def _create_car_modifier(self, func):
    def inner(self, car_id: str):
        car = self.api.get_driver_car(json.dumps({'car_id': car_id}))['car']
        if func(car) is None:
            return
        else
            return self.api.update_car({'car_id': car_id, 'data': json.dumps(self.create_car_request(car))})
    return inner
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much I finally refactored it!